# How to highlight a table column using intro.js

Tags: javascript, intro.js

Basically there is a need to highlight a whole table column using intro.js library.
Is there any way to achieve that feature?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe this is possible because HTML defines tables row-wise so there is no column element for `introJs` to introduce.